# How to distribute linear layout item equally with gravity

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout i'm trying to create a grid effect with use of linear layout and relative layout and i have succeeded in doing so but however the results are not accurate as desired the items in linear layout where orientation is set to horizontal were aligned horizontally but their gravity and alignment is getting changed whenever the item count i.e text changes i also tried using relative layout and grid layout but that didn't help any suggestions into this will be really appreciated.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_bg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/locklay"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi_shield"
            android:id="@+id/imgwifi"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgwifi"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="WiFi Thief Detector"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:id="@+id/imgsetting"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgwifi"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/lnr1"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/time"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_35ssp"
                        android:text="12:46"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imgwifi"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                        android:text="Wednesday, 10 July"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/time"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp">

                    <me.itangqi.waveloadingview.WaveLoadingView
                        android:id="@+id/indicator"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_120sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_18sdp"
                        app:wlv_shapeType="rectangle"
                        app:wlv_round_rectangle="false"
                        app:wlv_triangle_direction="west"
                        app:wlv_waveAmplitude="70"
                        app:wlv_waveColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_battery"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lnr1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:id="@+id/tvtitle"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Real-Time Protection Network"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:id="@+id/scanninganim"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    app:lottie_fileName="data.json"
                    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                    app:lottie_loop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_32sdp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_animation_circle"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp" />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_52sdp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_magnifier"
                        android:id="@+id/magnifyglass"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp" />

                    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                        android:id="@+id/wifiwiper"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_70sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:lottie_fileName="372-wifi-wiper.json"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                        app:lottie_loop="true"></com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/lywifiname"
                android:layout_below="@+id/scanninganim"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_wifi"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_35sdp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvwifiname"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvwifiname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Dlink Connected"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/lywifiname"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/lydevicesdet"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="100"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="50"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:text="125"
                            android:id="@+id/tvonlinedevicecount"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center|left"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:id="@+id/onlinetext"
                            android:text="Online Devices"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="50"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvstrangerdevicescount"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:text="125"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/onlinetext"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
                            android:text="Stranger Devices"
                            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="50"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:text="155"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center|left"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:id="@+id/tvofflinedevicecount"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_17sdp"
                            android:text="Offline Devices"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:id="@+id/tvoffdev"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="50"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:text="155"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:id="@+id/tvknowndevicescount"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvoffdev"
                            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_19sdp"
                            android:text="Known Devices"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center|right"
                            android:layout_weight="25"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/unlock"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lydevicesdet"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Swipe To Unlock"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_thin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use 'layout_weight' for equal width item and when you are using weight then your layout width should be layout_width="0dp"

Comment: I've already used but it didn't help

Comment: layout_width="0dp" do it in your text views

Comment: I'm facing issues with textviews where online devices and offline devices are there here if online device count is too large the other textview beside it is repositioned to right and i don't want this to happen

Comment: you can format the count as if its greater than 1000 you can format it to 1k may it helps

Comment: Setting width to 0dp doesn't work it just makes my textviews collapse

Comment: did you set it for both textviews in that Linear Layout

Comment: Yes i did that for both

Comment: @R.Coder can you try constraint layout. it is well suited for your case.

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" change it to wrap content in "tvonlinedevicecount"

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, `gravity/layout-gravity` is used to position view elements not to distribute space. You should use [layout_weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) for space distribution.

Comment: setting layout_width="0dp" should work , but it seems to not working in your case. If your properly distribute weight between child, then weightSum is not required. And try to use smaller value for weight distribution .

Answer (score 0):

use layout weight and weight sum. As a example if you need to create a 2 by 2 grid.

```
<!--Main parent layout-->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Then devide the main parent layout with two horizental layouts -->

    <!--First horizental layout-->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="verticle"
        android:layout_weight = "50"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <!--Then devide each horizental layouts vertically to get grid like elements-->

        <!--1st rows first column come here-->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="verticle"
            android:layout_weight = "50">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--1st rows second column come here-->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="verticle"
            android:layout_weight = "50">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--Second horizantal layout-->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:orientation="verticle"
        android:layout_weight = "50"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <!--2nd rows first column come here-->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="verticle"
            android:layout_weight = "50">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--2nd rows second column come here-->
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="verticle"
            android:layout_weight = "50">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***layout_weight*** to get applied to a view, you need to put ***layout_width*** or ***layout_height*** value as ***0dp***.

- For weights to get applied horizontally, we need to put ***layout_width*** as ***0dp***.
- For weights to get applied vertically, we need to put ***layout_height*** as ***0dp***.

> Example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use layout_weight like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/contParentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="19"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Online Device"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="19"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Online Device"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```